# HTTP GET in Angular 2 triggers a response received in my HTTP POST for Login

Tags: rest, angular, typescript, asynchronous

Hi I am fairly new to Angular 2 and I am getting http behavior that I can't understand.

Here is my login method that I use to do an http post to my backend and get my token. It works well.

```
public login(username, password) {

const headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa('live-test:')
});

const requestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers });

const urlSearchParamsLogin = new URLSearchParams();
urlSearchParamsLogin.append('grant_type', 'password');
urlSearchParamsLogin.append('client_id', 'live-test');
urlSearchParamsLogin.append('username', username);
urlSearchParamsLogin.append('password', password);

const paramsLogin = urlSearchParamsLogin.toString();

this.http.post(this.urlAuth, paramsLogin, requestOptions)
  .map(response => response.json().access_token)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      localStorage.setItem('token', response);
      alert(localStorage.getItem('token'));
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.text());
    }
  );
}
```

My checkToken method

```
public checkToken() {

const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

const urlSearchParamsCheckToken = new URLSearchParams();
urlSearchParamsCheckToken.append('token', token);

const paramsCheckToken = urlSearchParamsCheckToken.toString();

const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers , params: 
paramsCheckToken});

this.http.get('http://localhost:8082/cq-webapp/oauth/check_token', options )
  .map(response => response.json().user_name)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      alert(response);
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error.text());
    }
  );
 }

}
```

The checkToken method works fine except that after it gets its http response back from my Java backend, my login method above gets another response with the token (after it has already done so to get the token initially) . Why is my login method getting another response? Is this asychronous behavior that can be prevented by writing my Angular 2 a different way?

I don't think this is a problem with my Spring backend as Postman does not receive additional http responses with a checkToken HTTP GET. Fairly sure that this is an Angular 2 Typescript issue.

Any help?

****Update, Here was the fix. I still would be interested to hear why the html before was causing the login to be triggered with the checkToken button click.

Here is the html before

```
<div>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form role="form" (submit)="login(username.value, password.value)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" #username class="form-control" id="username" 
        placeholder="Username">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" #password class="form-control" id="password" 
        placeholder="Password">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>

    <button (click)="checkToken()" >Check Token</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Here is the html after

```
<div>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="username">Username</label>
    <input type="text" #username class="form-control" id="username" 
    placeholder="Username">
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" #password class="form-control" id="password" 
    placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button (click)="login(username.value, password.value)">Submit</button>

  <button (click)="checkToken()" >Check Token</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Where and how do you call these methods?

Comment: put a breakpoint in login method and see where the second call come from.

Comment: @JuliaPassynkova and Martin , thank you for your responses. I just realized my problem. It looks like the checkToken button with the (click)="checkToken()" was triggering the on submit of the form which was tied to the the login submit button. I am not sure how this was happening, but when I removed the submit logic at the top of the form and made the login button directly trigger the login function without the submit logic, it works fine. I am not sure why my checkToken button was being mistaken as a submit button when I had removed the type=submit from it.

Comment: @Martin and Julia, if you could tell me why my html was causing the checkToken click to trigger the login function again, I would be interested to hear. Thanks.

Comment: I think buttons default to type="submit",  so you can set `type="button"` or  `(click)="checkToken(); $event.preventDefault();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour happened because of missing `type` attribute on your checkToken button. When `type` attribute is not specified the default value is `submit` (except IE, so its better to specify it always).

Therefore when you clicked button the form submitted resulting in calling both `checkToken` (click) and `login` (submit).

Reference: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.5

> type = submit|button|reset [CI]
>
> **This attribute declares the type of the button. Possible values:**
>
> - submit: Creates a submit button. This is the default value.
> - reset: Creates a reset button.
> - button: Creates a push button.

Answer (score 0):

Use object instead of URLSearchParams

```
let user ={
    grant_type: 'password'
    client_id:  'live-test'
    username:  username);
    password':'password'
}

this.http.post(this.urlAuth, user, requestOptions);
```

You are Subscribing to the response in the component and not in the service itself, which causes you to wait for a long time.